# Listing products in Shopware based on variable send in URL

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

1. I have site.com/rims/?vehicleCode=P0000061000
2. If I filter the products with the code the default filters do not work.
3. In the install function in the Bootstrap.php file I subscribed the
     $this->subscribeEvent(
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Listing',
        'onPostDispatchListing'
     );
   event. After that in the onPostDispatchListing function I have:

   ```
   /** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
   $controller = $args->getSubject();
   $request = $controller->Request();

   // defines the default shopware VIEWS directory.
   $view = $controller->View();
   $view->addTemplateDir(
       __DIR__ . '/Views/responsive'
   );

   $shop = Shopware()->Shop();
   $sCategorystart = $shop->getCategory()->getId();
   $sCategoryID = $this->getCategoryCurrent($sCategorystart);

   $oDb = Shopware()->Db();
   $EngineCode = $request->getParam('sVehicle');
   $query = "SELECT va.`articleID` 
              FROM `s_vehicle_articles` as va
              INNER JOIN `s_articles_categories` as ac ON 
              ac.articleID=va.articleID
              WHERE ac.categoryID=" . $sCategoryID;
   $query .= ($EngineCode) ? " AND va.`VehicleCodeID`= '" . $EngineCode . "'" : " ";

   $mResults = $oDb->fetchAll($query);

   $articleModule = Shopware()->Modules()->Articles();
   $aProducts = array();

   foreach ($mResults as $key => $value) {
       $article = $articleModule->sGetArticleById($value['articleID'], $sCategoryID);
       $aProducts[] = $article;
   }

   $view->sArticles = $aProducts;
   ```
4. The code is working and the products are filtered but the default filters do not work, like price filter etc..

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't use default filters, because you rewrite default article list.

```
$view->sArticles = $aProducts;
```

Note: in your query you don't check important cafeterias like:

- Is product active.
- Is product have in stock available more then 0, in case this product have flag - don't show article in case in stock less then 1.
- Is product available for customer group.

As solution: you can subscribe these 2 events and add your query part:

```
$this->subscribeEvent( 
    'Shopware_Modules_Articles_GetArticleById_FilterSQL' => 'modifyQuery'
);
$this->subscribeEvent( 
    'Shopware_Modules_Articles_sGetArticlesByCategory_FilterSql' => 'modifyQuery'
);
```

Then check query and extend with your:

```
public function modifyQuery(\Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $args)
{
    $query = $args->getReturn();
    //Do some modifications
    $args->setReturn( $query );
    return $args->getReturn();
}
```

Better way - add your criteria to shopware `SearchBundle` `Condition`, but this case require some research, you can start from [this link](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-search-bundle/).

Comment: $criteria = new Criteria(); 
$criteria->addCondition(new CategoryCondition([3])); //My condition should be the code I send in the URL. How to set it up?   

$context = $this->get('shopware_storefront.context_service')->getShopContext();
$service = $this->get('shopware_search.product_number_search');

/**@var $result ProductNumberSearchResult*/
$result = $service->search($criteria, $context);

$numbers = [];
foreach($result->getProducts() as $product) {
   $numbers[] = $product->getNumber();
}

Comment: @DragiPostolovski, you should create your own criteria which implements ConditionInterface. But there not so easy, you should also add your model(did you register model for `s_vehicle_articles`) to search bundle query. Check my response with `modifyQuery` function, this way much easy for implementation.